# Is Freelancing taking part in Winterbash this year?

Tags: support, status-completed, winter-bash-2020

Is [Freelancing](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/) taking part in Winterbash this year?

Twelve hours in, and I can't believe nobody has qualified for at least the *Social Distancing* hat.
According to the [Leaderboard](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/freelancing.stackexchange.com) 0 Users have 0 Hats.

Or has a button not been pressed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apologies for the inconvenience here - we had a bunch of problems last night and Freelancing was an unfortunate victim that didn't recover itself like the other sites that were affected did. We've fixed the underlying issue and kicked some scheduled tasks into action - expect hats shortly!